# Does cloudcontrol support django gis?

Tags: cloudcontrol

In my deploy logs I'm getting:

`ImportError: Could not find the GEOS library (tried "geos_c", "GEOS"). Try setting GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH in your settings.`

Does cloudcontrol support the gis libraries?

Comment: it looks like i could use this custom buildpack: https://github.com/cirlabs/heroku-buildpack-geodjango/ will give it a go

Comment: yep that seems to have been the key